# design considerations for a WCF service to be accessed 500k times/day

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I've been tasked with creating a WCF service that will query a db and return a collection of composite types.  Not a complex task in itself, but the service is going to be accessed by several web sites which in total average maybe 500,000 views a day.

Are there any special considerations I need to take into account when designing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No special problems for the development side. 
Well designed WCF services can serve 1000's of requests *per second*.  [Here's a benchmark](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684.aspx) for WCF showing 22,000 requests per second, using a blade system with 4x HP ProLiant BL460c Blades, each with a single, quad-core Xeon E5450 cpu. I haven't looked at the complexity or size of the messages being sent, but it sure seems that on a mainstream server from HP, you're going to be able to get 1000 messages per second or more. And with good design, scale-out will just work.  At that peak rate, 500k per day is not particularly stressful for the commnunications layer built on WCF.

At the message volume you are working with, you *do* have to consider operational aspects.

**Logging**
Most system ops people who oversee WCF systems (and other .NET systems) that I have spoken use an approach where, in the morning, they want to look at basic vital signs of the system:

- moving averages of request volume:  1min, 1hr, 1day.
- comparison of those quantities with historical averages
- error/exception rate:  1min, 1hr, 1day
- comparison of those quantities

If your exceptions are low enough in volume (in most cases they should be), you may wish to log every one of them into a special application event log, or some other audit log.  This requires some thought - planning for storage of the audits and so on.  The reason it's tricky is that in some cases, highly exceptional conditions can lead to very high volume logging, which exacerbates the exceptional conditions - a snowball effect.   Definitely want some throttling on the exception logging to avoid this.  a "pop off valve"  if you know what I mean.

**Data store**
And of course you need to insure that the data source, whatever it is, can support the volume of queries you are throwing at it. Just as a matter of good citizenship - you may want to implement caching on the service to relieve load from the data store.

**Network**
With the benchmark I cited, the network was a pretty wide open gigabit ethernet. In your environment, the network may be shared, and you'll have to check that the additional load is reasonable.

Comment: Cheeso that link is an excellent link it's definately given me some learning materials.  Microsoft are a great company but sometimes their advertising of these sort of sample apps leaves a lot to be desired.  I took a look at the benchmark pdf document and it seems like they did a reasonable job in comparing the products.